# Running couple of commads in new terminal tabs in zsh

Tags: shell, zsh

I am having a scenario where I need to create a script file that runs a couple of commands.

- node index.js which runs continuously
- ./gradlew run which also run continuously
- some commands which will run and finish automatically

I want to write one script file that does all the jobs like running the node server, Gradle run, and also other commands.
I'm thinking of one of the approaches to creating a new terminal tab and executing the commands in it. But I'm unable to find the exact code to create a new tab irrespective of the operating system.

Comment: You did not even tell us which terminal are you using, so how can we know whether your terminal supports the possibility of opening a new tab by request of a program?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use one terminal for this. Just run a command in background. You can do this by adding `&` at the end of the line. The commands stdout will still log to the terminal session.

```sh
# Sorry for the Polish date 

while true; do echo $(date); sleep 2; done &
[1] 8873
czw, 28 paź 2021, 09:41:52 CEST
user@user-pc:~$ czw, 28 paź 2021, 09:41:54 CEST
czw, 28 paź 2021, 09:41:56 CEST
czw, 28 paź 2021, 09:41:58 CEST
```

If you want to bring back the job to the foreground `fg`.

```sh
user@user-pc:~$
user@user-pc:~$ fg
while true; do
    echo $(date); sleep 2;
done
czw, 28 paź 2021, 09:48:07 CEST
czw, 28 paź 2021, 09:48:09 CEST
^C
```

So the script finally could look like this:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

./task1 &
./task2 &
./task3
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate a bit more, considering my commands 
I have zsh and iTerm

Comment: The terminal emulator doesen't matter at this point. Zsh is a prettier and more functional bash. I assume that you work on MacBook so it will have bash installed. Create a text file, and write the commands like I wrote in the example. Make the file executable `chmod +x ./script.sh` and there you go.

Comment: It is stopping the first command after execution which means "node server stopped" as soon as "Gradle run" executes